# How to hide the keyboard using XCUITest API

Tags: xcuitest

I have an application where the keyboard is hiding the button that I'm trying to access. I get this error when I try to access it right now. The application doesn't support closing the keyboard with tap anywhere. Also the keyboard doesn't have any Done button usually supported in iOS keyboard.

```
Failed: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, {{25.0, 500.0}, {330.0, 41.0}}, identifier: 'enrollButton', label: 'Enroll', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction kAXScrollToVisibleAction on element AX element pid: 50265, elementOrHash.elementID: 140387766398144.11
```

Comment: Is there any button on the keyboard that can be used to close it or directly proceed? If yes - you could use something like `app.keyboards.buttons["Next"].tap()`. If not - then the second question: Can you swipe the app behind the keyboard to see the button? If yes - you can get the keyboard coordinates and swipe above them to show the button. If not - then you are blocked and you will need either the keyboard or the app updated to allow you to close the keyboard in some way - either by tapping `Done` or tapping outside it

Comment: Please share debug output and a screenshot.